# store multiple mediums events into one firestore collection?

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I wanted to ask one thing I have 3 medium Emails, SMS, push notification and I wanted to know is it possible to store all the events that come from the medium into firestore collection. I have done one part means I have stored the events of email into a firestore collection. is it possible to store all the mediums events into one collection?

Answer (score 0):

Firestore is a schemaless NoSQL database, so you can store many types of data in a collection. Whether that is a good idea, is something we can't say based on the information provided.

But if you're new to NoSQL data modeling in general, and Cloud Firestore specifically, I highly recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video). Both cover many of the concerns you'll run into.

Comment: it's more so related to aws problem. because i wanted to know is it possible to send the all medium data using one topic

Comment: I have one question is it possible to create a dynamic link using nodejs end to end ?

Comment: That's a complete separate question again. Please focus on a single, reasonably sized question, as I'm having a hard time figuring out what you're asking now. The answer to " is it possible to store all the mediums events into one collection?" is what I provided above.